# Uninstalling Android Application

Tags: android, uninstallation

When I create an Android project in Eclipse and send it to my device for debugging, the app works fine but when I try to uninstall it, I get a strange message. Below are the steps to recreate my problem:

Eclipse Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400

ADT Version: 2.0.3 v201208082019-427395

1. Run Eclipse
2. Click File->New->Project...
3. Select Android/Android Application Project
4. Click Next.
5. Enter Application Name: Test
6. Build SDK: Android 4.1
7. Minimum Required SDK: API 8 Android 2.2
8. Enable: Create custom launcher icon / Create project in workspace
9. Click Next thrice.
10. Click Finish.
11. Connect 4.1 Android device to computer via USB.
12. Click Run->Run from menu.
13. Select "Android application" on popup the "Run As" popup.
14. Click Ok.
15. MainActivity application runs on device.
16. Click the Back button on the Android device.
17. Open applications on device and find "MainActivity" app.
18. **Long press the MainActivity icon** and drag to trash.

Here's the puzzling part:

Instead of getting a standard

> Do you want to uninstall this app?

I get a dialog with this text:

> MainActivity is part of the following app: Test
>
> Do you want to uninstall this app?

1. Why do I get this message instead of the standard one?
2. Why is MainActivity the name of the app when I specifically stated the name of the app is "Test"?

Additional Information:
If I go to Settings->Apps, the Application shows up as Test but is listed in my Launcher as MainActivity.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Maybe it is still running. Have you stopped the program completely? Because sometimes when I run my programs on an AVD, after pressing back button it doesn't stop. Only the program disappeared and works on background.

Comment: @Squonk I'm new to Android/Java development so I'm assuming you mean the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @Behzad It's not still running.

Comment: @Sosukodo : Sorry, yes I meant the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It's often just referred to as the 'manifest' file. Try changing this line `android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >` in the `<activity>` section of the manifest file to `android:label="@string/app_name" >` and see if that changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to remove android:label="@string/title_activity_main" in the activity element.

The AndroidManifest.xml below solves the problem on Android 4.1.1 .

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your app name `app_name` is not styled.

Since I was using the app name somewhere else in the app I had made it bold, like this - In my strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name"><b>We are sons<b></string>
```

When I removed

```
<b></b>
```

tags, it worked.

Just keep it :

```
<string name="app_name">We are sons</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to solve the first issue but the second can be solved in the following way. The problem is connected with Android new project wizzard. To solve this problem you can correct your manifest file in the following way and redeploy your project:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Do not forget to check what is the value of `app_name`. Some more details you can find in [this post](http://zyrikby.blogspot.it/2012/09/android-labeling-issue.html)

Comment: Your changes (and the article you linked to) were almost correct. It seems I had to change the android:label from @string/title_activity_main to @string/app_name AND use the intent-filter change you suggested. Now it uninstalls without the strange "is a part of" message. Change the android:label inside the activity element to @string/app_name so I can accept the answer!

Comment: Just read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label and you'll see that yours and mine approaches are almost the same. In your case the name of your activity and the name in the launcher will be the same (as it was before). In my case the name of the activity and the name in the launcher will be different (thus, you will have possibility to use activity name somewhere else).

Comment: But your manifest doesn't solve my problem so I can't accept it. When I use your manifest, I have the same problem described in the question. When I remove android:label in the activity and intent-filter elements (or make both android:label properties the same) the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you tell what is the model of your phone? Maybe you should submit a bug to Google because of the differences in the documentation and actual behavior?

Comment: Galaxy Nexus i9250 stock w/ Android 4.1.1 .. What's yours?

Comment: The same ) I'll check this on the phone. I guess I tested this only on an emulator.